# SQL Data Type Mismatch

Tags: mysql, sql

When I run the below command:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE DOJ = '19-Feb-14';
```

An error message shows:

```
Data type mismatch in criteria expression.
```

Pls give me solution.

Comment: Use properly formatted dates, i.e. `'2014-02-19'`.

Comment: `Data type mismatch in criteria expression`  sounds like SQL  server or Acces database error.

Comment: If you’re wondering why the downvotes, it’s because this is an easily searchable question and pretty low-effort.

Answer (score 1):

If you used date type you should make a query in this style 'yyyy-mm-dd'

In your case it will be something like this (if I understood your code correct):

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE DOJ = '2014-02-19';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you used date type you should make a query in this style #yyyy-mm-dd#
then work it

```
**SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE DOJ = #2014-02-19#;**
```